# Why my overriding of the success.phtml is not working?

Tags: magento2, overrides, cache, phtml

I have copied and pasted the file from

> **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml**

to

> **app/design/frontend/THEME/THEMENAME/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml**

Modified some codes in that file, then after I  have

- cleared the cache
- removed file manually from `var/view_preprocessed` and `pub/static`

But my code won't is displayed in the **frontend**.

Searched already via **find command** for another `success.phtml` file but nothing found.

Any ideas to override the `success.phtml` page?

Comment: Do you use opcache in your environment ? If use opcache, you need restart opcache or disable.

Comment: If you solved this issue then please share solution.

Answer (score 19):

In Magento 2.4.1 there are two success.phtml templates:

```
module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml
module-inventory-in-store-pickup-frontend/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml
```

In my case, I had to override the second one in **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend/templates/success.phtml**

Comment: I've seen some pretty stupid things in Magento in my time, but this one is pretty stupid. Appreciate you figuring that out, thought I was going nuts.

Comment: Insanely stupid... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To the following:

```
rm -r var/cache/* var/generation/* var/log/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/_requirejs/* pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/frontend/* '
```

&

`php bin/magento setup:di:compil`e

after this: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: That's a bit overkill I guess when he's just adding a custom template. In fact `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands to set the developer mode and to regenerate all the static files.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento";

mage maintenance:enable &&
mage deploy:mode:set developer &&
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage cache:flush &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy -f && 
mage setup:di:compile && 
mage maintenance:disable
```