# How to get an order id in success.phtml block?

Tags: magento2, blocks, order-success-page

I created an own module for a new block in success.phtml. Read my old post here: 
[Magento 2: Override success.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195097/magento-2-override-success-phtml)

Now, I want to go get the order id in my own **success.phtml** file.

Tried with:

```
    $block->getOrderId() and $this->getOrderId()
```

but I don't get the id. Any idea what I need to call to get the order id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$block->getRealOrderId()`

Answer (score 1):

You will get Order **Increament id** from `$block->getOrderId()`.

If you want get Order id ,***object then you need to create an extension for create a plugin*** which change return value of **`AddData`**.

> app\code\{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\SuccessPlugin.php

```
    <?php
    namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin;

    class SuccessPlugin
{
    protected $orderFactory ;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;

    }


    public  function afterAddData(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success $subject
    ){
        $orderIncrementId = $subject->getData('order_id');
        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
        $subject->setData('current_order',$order);
    }


}
```

> app\code{VendorName}{ModuleName}\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success">
      <plugin name="onepage_order_details" type="{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\SuccessPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

At `success.phtml`, you will get order current place Order object by

```
$order = $block->getCurrentOrder();
$orderId= $order->getId();
$Order_customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
```

Comment: By using your code i get an error: Call to a member function getId() on null in my phtml file. Tryed also $this but same error

Comment: Can you please share folder structure of  the module. Do you have create module.xml, registration.php,composer.json?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZBRRPhif
all files and dirs