# How to get the order id in success.phtml?

Tags: magento2

i created an own module for a new block in success.phtml and created a Plugin in my own module. Read my old post here: [How to get an order id in success.phtml block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195315/how-to-get-an-order-id-in-success-phtml-block)

In my success.phtml file i have the following code:

```
$order = $block->getCurrentOrder();
$orderId= $order->getId();
```

On the successpage i get the following error:
Call to a member function `getId()` on null in

> app/code/Meta/Orderpage/view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml

Why its not possible to access the function?? Any error on the Code?

Comment: Have you tried: $block->getOrderId();

Comment: Are you sure that your checkout success  page phtml file location is `app/code/Meta/Orderpage/view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml`?

Comment: **Also, don't the as same question,Please comment on your previous  question or update the question?**

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my success.phtml file to get an order ID, and it works everytime:

**$orderID = $this->getOrderId();**

Then of course, if you want to show it, simply do something like this:

**echo  "Order ID: " . $orderID;**

Perhaps it is the "**$this**" part that makes the difference.

If it is any help, the path to my module and the success.phtml file is similar to this:

/app/code/company_name/myModule/view/frontend/templates/checkout/success.phtl

I hope this helps and answers your question.

Comment: This return the order Increment ID not the Order ID