# Magento 2 - Overriding Success Page

Tags: magento2, success-message

I'm trying to modify content in Thank you page, and the file I'm modifying is on the path: `Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/success.phtml`.
But it seems I'm missing something, because after many attempts and clearing cache several times, NO change reflects on the front end.

Please help how can I override and change the structure/content for thankyou/success page.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `phtml`files in `web/...`

Comment: For Magento 2.4 refer to the link
[override success.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/326297/81914)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to override **PHTML** file then you should use below path.

> Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

Don't forget to flush the cache.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
I have a question tho, my content.html (cart slider) file is in magento_checkout >web > template > minicart folder, so is this means that phtml files won't go under WEB folder but .html files goes there?
Also, my success page changes are now showing on front end, but after generating the content, I'm unable to find the success.phtml in my pub>static generated content whereas the content.html (cart slider) file is present there.

Comment: PHTMl files wont generate in pub>static folders.. only JS, CSS and Html files will go there.