# How can I add custom success page

Tags: magento2, order-success-page

I want to add custom success page by overriding it's phtml.

Can anyone guide me how can I do this?

Comment: If you can purchase the [Checkout success page](https://www.mageants.com/checkout-success-page-extension-for-magento-2.html) extension, it will allow you to Display full order summary, the recommended list of products, Customize the success page and descriptions for each block and section and many other features

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy This File :-

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml
```

And Paste In Your Theme :-

```
app/design/frontend/your/theme/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/templates/
```

**After This You Can Change Success Page As Per Your Requirement**

Comment: `Magento_Catalog` or `Magento_Checkout` ?

Comment: Magento_Checkout

Comment: Thanks Ronak Rathod, will try this one

Comment: most welcome...

Answer (score 5):

**Go to magento core file given path and Copy This File**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml

**And Paste In below path**

> app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme_name/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/templates/

Run below command

> php bin/magento c:c
>
> php bin/magento c:f

---

**You can also do it in module way**

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
<referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
    <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Success"
           name="test.order.success"
           template="Namespace_Modulename::order/success.phtml"
           after="-">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml

```
<?php echo __('Custom template file content.'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getSomething(); ?>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1

Comment: you are welcome. +1 for your appreciation :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by overriding or extending **`checkout_onepage_success.xml`** with your custom module. 
Follow these steps:

> 1. Create your **Success.php** Block file in **vendor\module\Block\OnePage**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Block\OnePage;
class Success extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getCustomSuccess()
    {
        return 'Your custom contents.';
    }
}
```

> 2. Create **checkout_onepage_success.xml** layout file in **vendor\module\view\frontend\layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
        <block class="vendor\module\Block\OnePage\Success"
               name="custom.order.success"
               template="Vendor_Module::order/success.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> 3. Lastly, create **phtml** template file in **vendor\module\view\frontend\templates\order\success.phtml**

```
<?php /* @var $block \vendor\module\Block\OnePage\Success */?>
<?php echo __('This is a custom content.'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getCustomSuccess(); ?>
```

After done with the above steps, run the upgrade command and redeploy static view files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

you need to copy

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml
```

into

```
app/design/frotend/<your package name/<your theme name>/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml
```

then do cache flush using below command

```
php bin/mageno c:f
```

Then check it

For Magento 2.4 refere below link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/326297/81914

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the template in my custom theme here: Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend/templates/success.phtml